# Meaning of "a burr had been a treasure trove" in Browning's Childe Roland

Tags: sentence-meaning, modal-verbs, poetry, elizabethan-english

From Browning's [Childe Roland](http://www.bartleby.com/246/654.html):

> So, on I went. I think I never saw
>     Such starv’d ignoble nature; nothing throve:
>     For flowers—as well expect a cedar grove!
>   But cockle, spurge, according to their law
>   Might propagate their kind, with none to awe,
>     You ’d think; **a burr had been a treasure trove**.

I don't get the meaning of this sentence. I understand that the burr here is

> A bur; a seed pod with sharp features that stick in fur or clothing. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burr))

But why a "treasure trove"? On first reading this line, I imagined that "cockle" and "spurge" were the names of some small birds, and for them even burrs were good, maybe as forage. But [on finding that these are the names of weed plants](https://books.google.ru/books?id=7dFohviLlOkC&lpg=PA328&ots=W6DH2QwVNM&dq=cockle%2C%20spurge&hl=ru&pg=PA328#v=onepage&q&f=false), I could no longer make sense of the bolded sentence.

And why "had been"? Why does the author use the Past Perfect?

---

[image]

Comment: In earlier editions there's a colon not semicolon. "You'd think: "

Comment: Compare Chaucer's *This Nicholas anon leet fle a fart / As greet as it had been a thonder-dent*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd never seen a landscape with such a dearth of vegetation. I don't just mean there were no flowers—you might as well expect a grove of cedars! But you'd think there'd at least be a lot of weeds—cockle and spurge ought to grow here—but No, even a burr would have been a rare treasure to find here.

*Had been* = *would have been*, with past-form *have* as an *irrealis*, was already archaic in Browning's day. Browning's syntax in this (and other poems aiming at a mediaeval or Renaissance flavor) is typically the Early Modern English of Jacobean playwrights.

Comment: Thank you, Stoney! So "Had been" is an antique form of "would have been". I don't see any inversion though, it just looks like an ordinary Past Perfect construction.

Comment: I thought that Browning begins to say "but no" in the next stanza only. "No! penury, inertness and grimace, \ In the strange sort, were the land’s portion." That's why I though that the line about the burr was not a negation, but a continuation of his "affirmative" musings. Such a tricky poem.

Comment: @CowperKettle Of course you're right -- I'll fix it.

Comment: I was going to comment making the same point about the archaic *You'd think [it] had been [something else]* - good job I scrolled down and saw this, 'cos I hadn't realized it was *already* at least "dated" at time of writing (deliberately used for its medieval connotations). I've upvoted because the answer is spot on, but I think the question itself is essentially Lit Crit, so I'm far from convinced it should be here in the first place.

Comment: It's parsing, @FumbleFingers, not lit-crit.

Comment: Since Browning was English, I suspect that the "burr" would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galium_aparine, or perhaps the common thistle (see http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/burrthistle) rather than the "cocklebur" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthium_strumarium

Comment: @TRomano: I remain far from convinced. Like you, I thought the next line started with ***But no!*** (and I'd only been *looking* at it seconds before reading your comment above! :) But in spite of OP's final line (which seems to be more or less tacked on as an afterthought), it seems to me the question focuses primarily on the *semantics* (specifically, why might a burr be a treasure-trove), and to me that's really just a matter of assessing the relationship between the elements being poetically juxtaposed (where obviously including the *next* line would have helped a lot).

Comment: @alephzero I'm no sort of naturalist, so I'll take it you're right!

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP's misunderstanding grew from his reading of *had been* as an ordinary past perfect rather than a "subjunctive".

Comment: I don't get "with none to awe".

Comment: I think *No!* in the next stanza is a continuation of *never* in "I think I never saw", and *nothing* in "nothing throve" and *none* in "none to awe"; that is, the next stanza is an emphatic continuation, not a change of mind.